# Centrar dos botones dentro de una columna

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

el problema que tengo el día de hoy es que estoy generando esta tabla HTML:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
<br>
<h2 class="text-secondary border border-secondary border-top-0 border-left-0 border-right-0 text-center">Lista de Paises</h2>
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="submit" value="Crear Pais" class="btn btn-success" />
  </div>
</div>

  <table class="table table-active text-center">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th>PAIS</th>
        <th>OPCIONES</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Mexico</td>
        <td>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <input type="submit" value="Editar" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <input type="submit" value="Eliminar" class="btn btn-danger" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

La cual como podrán observar los botones `editar` y `eliminar` están insertados en el lado izquierdo de la columna `OPCIONES`, lo cual vengo a pedirles su ayuda ya que los he tratado de corregir, **centrándolos** con CSS o en el mismo HTML pero no he logrado su cometido. Por lo que les pido que si pueden corregir el problema, centrando los botones me ayudarían muchísimo. Gracias

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En bootstrap 4 tienes la clase `justify-content-center` que puedes aplicar al div.row:

```
<td>
    <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="submit" value="Editar" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="submit" value="Eliminar" class="btn btn-danger" />
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Hola Rene, muchas gracias me funciono el "justify-content-center".

Answer (score 3):

Podrias dejar los dos botones dentro de un mismo div, de esta forma utilizas la clase `.text-center`

Te dejo el ejemplo:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
<br>
<h2 class="text-secondary border border-secondary border-top-0 border-left-0 border-right-0 text-center">Lista de Paises</h2>
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="submit" value="Crear Pais" class="btn btn-success" />
  </div>
</div>

  <table class="table table-active text-center">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th>PAIS</th>
        <th>OPCIONES</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let pais of pais">
        <td>Mexico</td>
        <td>
          <div class="form-group text-center">
              <input type="submit" value="Editar" class="btn btn-primary" />
              <input type="submit" value="Eliminar" class="btn btn-danger" />
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Orlando, gracias me centra los botones pero como estoy usando Angular, por una extraña razón estos se juntan y por ello use un <div> para separarlo. Pero te agradezco tu tiempo.